# How use the same Socket to multiples InputStreamReader and OutputStreamWriter

Tags: java, sockets

I am creating a irc client in java . At first I used a socket for each channel that would connect , for example:

```
String server = " ircServer " ;
int port = " 6667 " ;
Channellist String [ ] = { " channel 1 " , " Canal2 " " canal3 " , ...} ;

for ( String s : channellist ) {
    Socket socket = new Socket (server , port ) ;

    InputStreamReader InputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader ( socket.getInputStream ());
    OutputStreamWriter OutputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter ( socket.getOutputStream ());

    // ... Code to connect the channel
}
```

But this approach does not work on some servers , because they claim many connections from the same IP , and this is due to the use of several instantiated sockets.

So , I wonder , how can I use N InputStreamReader and OutputStreamWriter with the same socket, preventing excessive connections to the server . Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You're not supposed to use multiple readers/writers in the same socket. Imagine trying to hold several conversations using a single phone.

A single connection is enough, and the IRC protocol multiplexes that to handle the communication to/from different channels. The send message command is after all `/msg <channel> <msg>` allowing you to send to any number of channels from a single writer.

Answer (score 0):

try with java nio channels. may they solve your problem

Comment: how I could use the java nio channels that my context ? I've never used it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Kayaman, Thanks for the answer. To send messages I get it , but would like to join more than one channel using the same InputStreamReader and OutputStreamWriter . For example,
after the above code it performs these codes :

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader ( this.inputStreamReader ) ;
BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter ( this.outputStreamWriter ) ;

writer.write ( " NICK " + " myNickName " + "\ r \ n");
writer.write ( " JOIN" + " ircChannel " + "\ r \ n");
writer.flush ();

String line = null;
while ( (line = reader.readLine ( ) ) ! = null)
System.out.println (line ) ;
```

With the writer I can join the channel , and the reader I can be listening to what happens in the channel. So how would I do to connect to more than one channel , and to listen to them all?

Thank you very much.